# VB.NET compare date time from string format

Tags: vb.net

I have this string: `28 June 2018 (22:05)`

How can I compare it with my current time and get the difference?

For example if actual time was `29/06/2018 (05:49)`

The difference will be: `7 hours 44 minutes`

So input: `28 June 2018 (22:05)`
Output: `7 hours 44 minutes`

Comment: Getting the difference is not a comparison.  When you subtract one number from another, are you comparing them?  Comparisons are testing for equality, or relative magnitude, i.e. less than or greater than. A subtraction is just a subtraction.

Comment: Note that, if you subtract one `Date` from another and you want the resulting `TimeSpan` to be positive regardless of which `Date` is greater than the other, call the `Duration` method of that `TimeSpan`. It's basically the same as `Math.Abs` is for numbers.

Comment: And to know if it's negative or positive you're not comparing? I think you are. How do you think duration method is working? I'm testing one date against another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do, is convert the string to a valid DateTime instance.

If you know your dates will always be in this format, you can do the following...

```
Dim mydate = DateTime.ParseExact("28 June 2018 (22:05)", "dd MMMM yyyy (HH:mm)", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Once you've parsed the string into a valid DateTime instance, you can use all the normal date functions to do the comparisons.

I would first get the difference in minutes, like so...

```
Dim diffminutes = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, mydate, Now)
```

Then create a timespan like this...

```
Dim mytimespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(diffminutes)
```

Finally display the difference in hours and minutes like this...

```
Response.Write(mytimespan.ToString("hh\:mm"))
```